# Is it still possible to dual-boot Ubuntu Touch on Android?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

For the last couple days I've been attempting to find ways to dual-boot Ubuntu on my Android device as a personal project for school. It would seem there used to have been Ubuntu-supported methods for this, but have since been deprecated. Other popular 3rd party Dual-Boot methods like MultiROM and Dual Boot Patcher haven't seen developmental updates since 2017 at the latest.

Dual Boot Patcher still seems to have it's files hosted and active, but doesn't seem to be functional on my Samsung Galaxy A6 (SM-A600GN) and all websites hosting resources for MultiROM seem to be unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported method of dual booting Ubuntu Touch, no. Also, your stated device is not supported. See the [list of supported devices](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io).